# How can I display a view based on a database value

Tags: django, django-views

I want to use one view (URL) for 2 conditions.

In my application, "owners" create daily plans for routes they manage, and update the plans/results throughout the day.

```
class DailyRoute(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver)
    stops = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, ...
    on_duty_hours = models.TimeField(default=datetime.time...
    date = models.Datefield(...
    finalized = models.Boolean(...
```

Essentially, there are 3 database conditions, 2 of which I'm trying to use for a view:

1. No database row for the date/route. This means that the owner hasn't created a plan for the day. (e.g. if DailyRoute.objects.filter(stage = 0).count() == 0:...)
2. A database row for the date/route with finalized = False. This means that a plan has been created for the day for the date/route pair and can be edited.
   (e.g. DailyRoute.objects.filter(stage = 0).count() >0 )
3. A database row for the date/route with finalized = True. This means that a plan/updates for the day are complete and no further edits are allowed. (e.g. if DailyRoute.objects.filter(stage = 1).count() > 0:...)

As a daily activity, I want the user to go to a URL (e.g. /account/daily) and be presented with one of these views:

a) If no owner routes (point 1 above), provide an "Add" button to add a row for each owned route for a specific date (i.e. next business day). On success, display the DailyRoute List as per b) below.

b) If owner routes exist in the 0 state, display the list (i.e. don't display the "Add" button.)

Note that an owner can never have more than one date / route pair in the 0 state. They must complete the day's activities on 0 state routes before they can plan the next days routes.

Alternatively, it would be acceptable to have View with a disabled "Add" button and a list of routes, if routes are in the 0 state. Conversely, the "Add" button would be enabled and an empty list of routes, if no routes are found.

Right now I can do this with separate URLs, one for add daily plan, the other to display a list of routes in stage=0, but it would be much better to do this all on the same URL.

I can't figure out how/where to add a filter to a view to do this.
Thanks in advance for guidance.

Comment: What have you tried? A view can have an `if ... else` condition that renders different templates depending on the situation. Or it can set different context variables that you then handle in the same template with `{% if daily_route.finalized %}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, sounds like a simple `if/else` statement would do the trick:

```
class YourView(View):
    if first_condition:
        return render('first_template')
    else if second_condition:
        return render('second_template')
    else:
        return render('third_template')
```

Or, if you want to use one template, you can do this `if/else` inside your template. I also suggest that you send that flag from your view:

```
class YourView(View):
    ...
    routes_exist = DailyRoute.objects.filter(stage = 0).exists()
    return render('template.html', {'routes_exist': routes_exist})
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if routes_exsist %}

    <button> Add </button>

{% endif %]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but how to do this with ListView?

Comment: Ignore that - I've been looking at this for too long. Your answer is perfect. Thanks again.